# DateTime to LocalDate (NodaTime)

Tags: c#, datetime, localtime, nodatime

I have a `DateTime` that needs to be converted to a `NodaTime LocalDate`. Can this be done?

I have this:

```
 DateTime modifiedDate = File.GetLastWriteTime(file);
```

And I want this:

```
LocalTime modifiedDate = File.GetLastWriteTime(file);
```

But it looks like  `NodaTime` **API** can not get a date value from `GetLastWriteTime`.

So I either need to 
a) Convert the DateTime to LocalTime or 
b) somehow use LocalTime to get a date value from `GetLastWriteTime`

Comment: Do you mean a LocalTime or LocalDate? You specify both in your question. There is `LocalDateTime.FromDateTime()` that exists, can this help you?

Comment: You say it can't get a value. But what is the exception?

Answer (score 9):

One of the principle design decisions of Noda Time, is that there should be no side-effects created by local time zone setting of the computer.  Internally,  `GetLastWriteTime` calls `GetLastWriteTimeUtc().ToLocalTime()`.  So just by calling `GetLastWriteTime`, you are violating this ideal.

The correct Noda Time type to read a file time would be an `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(File.GetLastWriteTimeUtc(file));
```

From there, if you desire a local date and/or time, then you can apply a time zone.

First, decide what time zone you want.  For example:

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["America/New_York"];
```

If you want for some reason to use the computer's own local time zone, then use this:

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetSystemDefault();
```

Then apply the time zone to the instant of your file time:

```
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = instant.InZone(zone);
```

Then you can pick from any of these, depending on what exactly you're looking for:

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = zonedDateTime.LocalDateTime;
LocalDate date = zonedDateTime.Date;
LocalTime time = zonedDateTime.TimeOfDay;
```

Also, you should understand that on disk, the file time is dependent on the type of file system you're working with.

- If you are working with NTFS, the time on disk is recorded in UTC.  This is highly desired.
- If you are working with exFAT, the time on disk is recorded in local date + time, but it also includes the offset from UTC, so it is easily translated back to UTC without ambiguity.
- If you are working with FAT or FAT32 file systems, the time on disk is recorded using the local time, by the time zone that's in effect *when the file is written*.

  This creates ambiguous data, as you might be writing to a file during a [daylight saving time](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info) fall-back transition, or you might be reading the data using a different time zone setting, or a different computer entirely.

  This is a good reason to format any USB thumbdrive or SD cards you might use as exFAT instead of FAT32.

Comment: this seems insanely complex

Comment: @NimChimpsky - Which part?  Care to clarify?

Comment: To get a localdate with todays date in noda-time I have to do similar code (?). Whereas in java joda-time I just instantiate a new localdate() with no args.

Comment: Understood.  But that's part of [the Noda Time design philosophy](http://nodatime.org/1.2.x/userguide/design.html).  I'm sure some debate about this would be welcome on [the Noda Time Google Group](https://groups.google.com/group/noda-time).

Comment: Ah, I was hoping I'd got it wrong somehow. Ok thanks.